# java SDK in eclipse for scala & play : a class in a jar is not found

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar, sms-gateway

[have a look there!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ib9e.jpg)

here's the screenshot of a picture showing a play project in eclipse, containing an unmanaged library named Trendoo3.jar, whose content is displayed in the unzipper window.
I don't understand this : eclipse shows me some stuff in autocompletion when I begin to add an import : "import com.oe.sdk..." but eclipse does not find the class SMSCConnection.java...

can you tell me how I can make eclipse recognize the classes in this jar?I add there is neither a main class nor a classpath in the MANIFEST.MF file.

thanks.

Comment: I guess you are missing binary .class files in the jar, rather then .java source files

Comment: ok, obviously! thanks.